# Creating a Kendo chart view from my model class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm new to both the MVC framework and Kendo, so you'll have to bear with me. Here's my chart base class (the DatedChart class I'm using is just a chart of type `<DateTime, double>`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Project.Models.Charts
{
    public class NewChart<XType, YType> : IMailListener
        where XType:IComparable 
        where YType:IComparable
    {
        public Dictionary<string, DataSeries<XType, YType>> SeriesList { get; protected set;  }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string XLabel { get; set; }
        public string YLabel { get; set; }

        public NewChart(string title, string xLabel, string yLabel)
        {
            this.SeriesList = new Dictionary<string, DataSeries<XType, YType>>();
            this.Title = title;
            this.XLabel = xLabel;
            this.YLabel = yLabel;
        }

        public void AddSeries(DataSeries<XType, YType> series)
        {
            this.SeriesList.Add(series.Name, series);
        }

        public virtual void OnUpdate(IEnumerable<MailEntry> mail)
        {
            foreach (var ds in this.SeriesList.Values)
            {
                ds.OnUpdate(mail);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the class for the data series:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Project.Models.Charts
{
    public abstract class DataSeries<XType, YType> : IMailListener
        where XType : IComparable
        where YType : IComparable
    {
        public string Name;
        public List<Pair<XType, YType>> values { get; private set; }

        protected DataSeries(string name)
        {
            this.Name = name;
            this.values = new List<Pair<XType, YType>>();
        }

        public abstract void OnUpdate(IEnumerable<MailEntry> mail);
    }
}
```

What I need to do is to create a view that will display one of these charts. I've read a lot of examples, but it's hard for me to see how they apply to what I'm trying to do - a lot of them gloss over how to fit your view around an arbitrary model. I don't need anything fancy for an example, just something that will show me how to get the data from one of these charts into a format where Kendo's LineChart class can display the series. My view might look something like this:

```
@using DatedChart = Project.Models.Charts.DatedChart
@using DatedSeries = Project.Models.Charts.DataSeries<System.DateTime, double>
@model DatedChart

<div class="nice-module nice-smallchart center">
    // Magic here?
</div>
```

Any hints?

EDIT:

**Explanation of the model**
My model consists of Chart objects, where each chart has a title, x-axis, y-axis, and a set of one or more data series. Each series is a different set of points (i.e. it will be in its own color, and if it's a line chart, only those points will be connected with each other). I made the base Chart class parameterized so that the X and Y axes can have any type, but for now I'm just using DateTime objects for the X type and doubles for the y type, hence the DatedChart which will have series whose data points are pairs of . An example of this chart model would be a graph showing the reputation of four Stack Overflow users over a month period. Each user would have his or her own series of points (x, y), where x is the DateTime of a day, and y is a count o posts.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't get how your model works (What is *DatedChart* etc.) but here is how would I draw chart:

**Model**

```
public class Pair<XType, YType>
{
    public XType X { get; set; }
    public YType Y { get; set; }
}

public class ChartModel<XType, YType>
{
    public List<Pair<XType, YType>> Data { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller Action**

```
public ActionResult Test()
{
    ChartModel<int, int> model = new ChartModel<int, int>();
    model.Data = new List<Pair<int, int>>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Pair<int, int> p = new Pair<int, int>();
        p.X = i;
        p.Y = i;
        model.Data.Add(p);
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

**View**

```
@model ChartModel<int, int> 

 <div id="chart"></div>

<script>
    function createChart() {
        $("#chart").kendoChart({
            title: {
                text: "Chart title"
            },
            legend: {
                position: "bottom"
            },
            seriesDefaults: {
                type: "line"
            },
            series: [{
                name: "Serie name",
                data: [
                    @foreach (var item in Model.Data)
                    {
                        @item.X.ToString()@:,
                    }
                    ]
                    }],
            valueAxis: {
                labels: {
                    format: "{0}%"
                },
                line: {
                    visible: false
                }
            },
            categoryAxis: {
                categories: [
                    @foreach (var item in Model.Data)
                    {
                        @item.Y@:,
                    }],
                majorGridLines: {
                    visible: true
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                visible: true,
                format: "{0}%",
                template: "#= series.name #: #= value #"
            }
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(createChart);
</script>
```

Comment: I edited my post a bit to explain what I was thinking about my model. I'll have a closer look at your code tomorrow when I'm at my dev machine. I notice that your ActionResult populates the model object, though - since my model is obviously already populated with data by my backend, can I just return the object?

Comment: *ChartModel* is just an example. You may have any type of model.

Comment: So I'm trying to use Kendo's automatic DataSource binding, rather than generating the JSON from a custom view, which is why I had trouble correlating your answer with the examples. Do you know anything about binding to a model that isn't tailor-made for the default format that Kendo expects? Can I specify a custom way to read values out of the JSON while still leveraging data binding?

Comment: It would be better to ask this on kendo's forum http://www.kendoui.com/forums.aspx